# handling multiple dropdown button opening at same time in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I am working in Angular ,

- Where I have created a tree based structure
- on going down to tree structure there is a **dropdown button name
  "Dropdown"**
- **Problem** is on clicking to "Dropdown" button **multiple dropdown is opening at same time**
- Kindly check I am putting stackblitz link below for the code

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tree-un?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Every dropdown button sets the same `vaccanttoggle` variable. All dropdowns show  or hide based on this same variable. Thus every dropdown button will toggle all dropdowns. You need to control every dropdown menu individually.

Comment: Please do not paste links to external sites that contain your code. Paste the contents there as the question will lose all its meaning if the link dies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The button needs to toggle the corrosponding node. Everytime the dropdown button is clicked the value which determines if the dropdown should change in the node. Add isSelected as a property to the nodes and check if a node should show based on this property. Im not sure why you handle that vaccant node like that but the normal nodes should just work like this.
Using Akhil's code since you've already tested it adjust it to this:

```js
{ 
name: "Raghavendran M",
me_code: "6000001",
tl_code: "N.A.",
rs_id: "09565792-c288-4885-a4ed-3dd055f250f5",
role: "ME",
isSelected:false 
}


myFunction(value,node){
    node.isSelected = !node.isSelected;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
<button (click)="myFunction(1,node)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
<div id="myDropdown" class='dropdown-content' *ngIf='node.isSelected' >
<a href="#">Link 1</a>
<a href="#">Link 2</a>
<a href="#">Link 3</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing `if(1)` and `if(2)`, keep the condition like below:

```
     if(value===1){ 
        this.availableBtn = !this.availableBtn;
     }

     if(value===2){
        this.vaccanttoggle = !this.vaccanttoggle;
     }
```

Comment: It didn't worked at all , I think we have to do some changes in dom

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. added extra property isSelected for TREEDATA children

```
{ 
name: "Raghavendran M",
me_code: "6000001",
tl_code: "N.A.",
rs_id: "09565792-c288-4885-a4ed-3dd055f250f5",
role: "ME",
isSelected:false 
}


myFunction(value,node){
    if(value==1){
       this.availableBtn = !this.availableBtn;
       if(!this.availableBtn){
          node.isSelected=false;
       }else{
        node.isSelected=true;
       }
    }

    if(value==2){
       this.vaccanttoggle = !this.vaccanttoggle;
    }
  }
```

in HTML ->

```
<div class="dropdown">
<button (click)="myFunction(1,node)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
<div id="myDropdown" class='dropdown-content' *ngIf='availableBtn && node.isSelected' >
<a href="#">Link 1</a>
<a href="#">Link 2</a>
<a href="#">Link 3</a>
</div>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tree-un-ka8cx5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: this sollution has a problem , when I am clicking to one dropdown , then clicking another dropdown , it affects first dropdown also .

Just check >>>> click 1st dropdown . then click 2nd dropdoen then again click to 1st dropdown